# SQLite data retrieve with select taking too long

Tags: sqlite, select, lua, coronasdk

I have created a table with sqlite for my corona/lua app. It's a hashtable with ~=700 000 values.The table has two columns, which are the hashcode (a string), and the value (another string). During the program I need to get data several times by providing the hashcode.

I'm using something like this code to get the data:

```
for p in db:nrows([[SELECT * FROM test WHERE id=']].."hashcode"..[[';]]) do
    print(p) 
    -- p = returned value --
end
```

This statement is though taking insanely too much time to perform

thanks,

Edit:

Success!
the mistake was with the primare key thing.I set the hashcode as the primary key like below and the retrieve time whent to normal:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (id STRING PRIMARY KEY , array);
```

I also prepared the statements in advance as you said:

```
stmt = db:prepare("SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = ?;")
[...]
stmt:bind(1,s)
for p in stmt:nrows() do
```

The only problem was that the db file size,that was around 18 MB, went to 29,5 MB

Answer (score 2):

You should create the table with `id` as a unique primary key; this will automatically make an index.

```
create table if not exists test
(
    id text primary key,
    val text
);
```

You should not construct statements using string concatenation; this is a security issue so avoid getting in this habit. Also, you should prepare statements in advance, at program initialization, and run the prepared statements.

Something like this... initially:

```
hashcode_query_stmt = db:prepare("SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = ?;")
```

then for each use:

```
hashcode_query_stmt:bind_values(hashcode)
for p in hashcode_query_stmt:urows() do ... end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that there is an *index* on the `id`/hashcode column? Without one such queries will be *slow, slow, slow*. This index should probably be unique.

If only selecting the value/hashcode (`SELECT value FROM ..`), it may be beneficial to have a *covering index* over `(id, value)` as that can avoid additional seeking to the row data (see [SQLite Query Planning](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html)). Try it with and without such a covering index.

Also, it may be worthwhile to employ *caching* if the same hashcodes are queried multiple times.

Comment: +1 for the index, -1 for caching (rarely pays off in sqlite, since the row will be in the CPU cache anyway and no network I/O is involved.)

Comment: when you say covering index you mean a numerical index, like 1,2,3,4... would it be helpfull?

Comment: @ossumsiul A covering index is an compound index that *also* contains additional data required by the query result (which has the benefit of mitigating an additional access of the primary record and has a side-effect of duplicating the physical data). For instance a compound index over *both* `(id, value)` "covers" the `value` column, even though only the `id` column (which appears in the WHERE) is used to find the `value`. The article on the SQLite query planner in the post does a pretty good job of explaining how this *may* help.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, get sure you have an index on ID.

If you can't change table schema now, you can add a index ad hoc:

```
CREATE INDEX test_id ON test (id);
```

About hashes: if you are computing hashes in your software to speed up searches, don't!

SQLite will use your supplied hashes as any regular string/blob. Also, RDBMS are optimized for efficient searching, which may be greatly improved with indexes.

Unless your hashing to save space, you are wasting processor time computing hashes in your application.